# div with fixed size should not split number on half

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If I have numbers in a sequence, and those numbers are displayed inside div wrapper with fixed size. How can I prevent those numbers to be break on two digits numbers, for example if number is 45 I do not want to break this number to be 4 at the end of first line and 5 on the beggining of the second line.

for example, given sequence numbers are

```
1 2 3 10 20 45 91 92 93 94
```

if fixed div size has a width to break this numbers I want to break like this

```
1 2 3 10 20 45
91 92 93 94
```

and not

```
1 2 3 10 20 4
5 91 92 93 94
```

Comment: basically you want to short number collection and display in grid ...am I correct ?

Comment: What did you try? If the number is split then you should make your div just slightly bigger or adjust your padding.

Comment: script please.. it would be more clear if fiddle is provide

Answer (score 3):

Use `word-break`

```css
#content{
    width: 45px;
    word-break: keep-all;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">1 2 3 10 20 45 91 92 93 94</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this for sorting

```
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
points.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
```

than use jquery to print in div

```
var text;
jQuery.each(points, function(i, val) {
    text+= val + " ";
});

$('#myDIV').html(text);
```